# Correctly set headers for Laravel 5 CSRF Token

Tags: angularjs, laravel, csrf, restangular

Alright, been searching this one for hours and just can't find the start of a solution.

I am using an angularJS frontend with a laravel backend. Restangular is my communcation service.

My POST are fine, because I can include the _token in the data and it will work.

But for Restangular to call a destroy function it looks like...

```
Restangular.all('auth/logout').remove(); //maps to AuthController@Destroy
```

All fine, but then you will get a TOKENMISMATCH Exception, which is a good security messure

Since I can't find a way to include the _token into the remove, since it's body-less essentially, I decided to put the token in the header.

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'X-XSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN}); //CSRF_TOKEN gathered elsewhere
```

Out of the Chrome dev tolos, I can see the header is set to

```
X-XSRF-TOKEN:ClkQIRLpFQgMg8ZT6X5CF6doCplRfdJzW8msx2JI
```

X-XSRF-TOKEN is *exactly* what the VerifyCrsfToken.php is looking for. Yet, it spits out a decrypt error. Any other token name, such as XSRF-TOKEN, _TOKEN, CSRF_TOKEN all spit out token mismatch.

Because of that last fact, it seems like the header is declared correctly, but something beyond my comprehension is causing Laravel to fail the decrypt. And I've closely at the decrypt function, but don't understand why it'd fail...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to encryption of the csrf token. Laravel expect the token to be encrypted.

It tries to decrypt the the plain token you provide and it fails.

Before you can use the token in the header you have to encrypt it.

```
$encrypter = app('Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter');
$encrypted_token = $encrypter->encrypt(csrf_token());
```

That did the trick for me.

Alex

Comment: I eventually tried this, but since my angular app has a degree of separation, I didn't know how to encrypt it exactly.

What I later found is that since Laravel 5 is still in production, the creator added a useful line to the verifycsrf.php that made the token available in the cookie. Which really helped out!

https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/140d235cbb532b1ce7a80f5c2e3ddc23cf7f0c39

Comment: @csduarte is correct about the XSRF-TOKEN cookie also being set during the request lifecycle.  I FINALLY got all my AJAX working fully (where no _token was being set on the form for various reasons) by updating my VerifyCsrfToken.php middleware to also check `$request->cookie('XSRF-TOKEN')` if it's set.

Comment: @dcarrith Could you please share the code how you got your VerifyCsrfToken middleware to work? Would be really usefull! If I understand correctly, by doing this, there is no need to manually set the token header in angular, as it is done automatically.

Comment: where this "$encrypter = app('Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter');
$encrypted_token = $encrypter->encrypt(csrf_token());" should be put or applied?

Answer (score 3):

For Laravel 5, **no need** to add CSRF token to Angular http headers.

Laravel 5 with Angular do this automatically for you.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-x-xsrf-token