# Laravel Form sessioin expires after couple of hours

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2. I am getting an issue. I have a form on a page. The problem is if user opens a form and leave for 2 to 3 hours and then tries to submit it gives TokenMismatch Error. It only happens on server not on my local.

Here is the error that I get [image]

I have read about this some where and solution was to wrap routes in `web middlewear`. I did that but issue persists. My routes are grouped like

```
  Route::group(
[
    'middleware' => ['dealer', 'web'],
    'prefix' => 'dealer_panel'
],
function () {
      //all routes here
});
```

I am using a shared hosting for Laravel (I know Laravel isn't for shared hostings but I have to deal with it). This error never happens on local but it always happen on server. I always use `Laravel Form helper` to generate form like

```
 {!! Form::open(['route' => ['dealer.profile.save'], 'id' => 'location_form', 'files' => true]) !!}
```

And I have verified token is generated. But it gets expired after 2, 3 hours. How do I stop it to break/expires and what is the way to deal with this problem

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27330609/5139222) or [this](http://laravel.io/forum/01-30-2015-laravel5-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken) ?

Comment: @KuKeC Yes but no benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the token session time in based on **config/session** **lifetime** attribute.You can either increase it or as an alternative you can check with the following things

1) In your **App\Exceptions\Handler** file

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('token', csrf_token());
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

2) Another way is in your middleware also you can create a new token.

3) using ajax you can setInterval time to reresh token

```
    <meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var csrfToken = $('[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

        setInterval(refreshToken, 3600000); // 1 hour 

        function refreshToken(){
            $.get('refresh-csrf').done(function(data){
                csrfToken = data; // the new token
            });
        }

        setInterval(refreshToken, 3600000); // 1 hour 

    </script>

    Route::get('refresh-csrf', function(){
      return csrf_token();
    });
```

Comment: Let me try this

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make them login again. You can handle the token mismatch like,

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException){
        //Redirect to login form if session expires
        return redirect('/')->with('login_fail',"Your session has expired, please try again. In the future, reload the current page if it has been open for several hours.");
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pages which use `csrf_token` only have problems with this. I had this problem in my app with token expired time. So simplest way to get rid of this problem is to add meta tag which refresh your page each n minutes. No need to use ajax or whatever, the page will refresh before token expires and you won't have this problem anymore.

For example if your token expires in 1 hour, refresh page each 55 mins or so.

Meta tag which refresh your page is below

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">
```

Value 900 represents 15 mins in my example. 15mins * 60 seconds = 900

Comment: Great apart from the usability disadvantage this could present i.e. refreshing during a user operation like filling a form.

Comment: This is a bad solution as explained above. The user will lose all their work when filling a form.